# Any difference between type assertions and the newer `as` operator in TypeScript?

Tags: casting, typescript

Is there any difference between what the TypeScript spec calls a type assertion:

```
var circle = <Circle> createShape("circle");
```

And the [newer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new-tsx-file-extension-and-as-operator) `as` operator:

```
var circle = createShape("circle") as Circle;
```

Both of which are typically used for compile-time casting?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

The difference is that `as Circle` works in TSX files, but `<Circle>` conflicts with JSX syntax. `as` was introduced for this reason.

For example, the following code in a `.tsx` file:

```
var circle = <Circle> createShape("circle");
```

Will result in the following error:

> error TS17002: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for 'Circle'.

However, `as Circle` will work just fine.

Use `as Circle` from now on. It's the [recommended](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#new-tsx-file-extension-and-as-operator) syntax.

Comment: In my code, I tried using a string value as a key for returned JSX in the map function but I did get a type error over and over. The old casting method didn't work but only when used 'as' operator the error disappeared! <3

Answer (score 43):

From [Wiki page](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new-tsx-file-extension-and-as-operator): "What's new in TypeScript [1.6]":

> New `.tsx` file extension and `as` operator
>
> TypeScript 1.6 introduces a new `.tsx` file extension. This extension
>   does two things: it enables JSX inside of TypeScript files, and it
>   makes the new `as` operator the default way to cast (removing any
>   ambiguity between JSX expressions and the TypeScript prefix cast
>   operator). For example:
>
> ```
> var x = <any> foo; 
> // is equivalent to:
> var x = foo as any;
> ```

Comment: is any different on this two?

```var x = foo as any;  
var x: any = foo;```

Comment: @yusunglee better answer to your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69220403/is-there-a-difference-between-as-type-operator-and-classical-typing-in-typescr?noredirect=1#comment122344292_69220403

Answer (score 1):

One important difference is the precedence of these two operators. For example in AssemblyScript which you may consider like a stricter TypeScript, you may more often feel the need to decide on using one or the other.

```
const COPY_FROM : usize = <u64>start >>> 6 as usize;
```

`start` which is a number type casted into unsigned 64 bit integer, right shifted by 6 bits and the result is casted to `<usize>` pointer type. Which is exactly the desired behaviour.

However

```
const COPY_FROM : usize = <u64>start >>> <usize>6;
```

is not what we want and wouldn't even compile. Yet,

```
const COPY_FROM : usize = <usize>(<u64>start >>> 6);
```

is harder to read and not so pretty.

However as I understand for some unknown reason the precedence of `as` is not low enough to be a trailing operator. For example had the  above code be like;

```
const COPY_FROM : usize = <u64>start & 63 as usize; // start % 64
```

then it would either throw or yield wrong result as seemingly the precidence of `as` is higher than the `&` operator. So we best be careful using it.