# Angular2 Mapping nested json array to model

Tags: arrays, json, angular, observable

I am not able to map the nested json array  which is response from Web to my model array in Angular2. Suppose I have json array response as below:

```
[{
    "base_url": "http://mysearch.net:8080/",
    "date": "2016-11-09",
    "lname": "MY PROJ",
    "name": "HELLO",
    "description": "The Test Project",
    "id": 10886789,
    "creationDate": null,
    "version": "2.9",
    "metrics": [{
        "val": 11926.0,
        "frmt_val": "11,926",
        "key": "lines"
    },
    {
        "val": 7893.0,
        "frmt_val": "7,893",
        "key": "ncloc"
    }],
    "key": "FFDFGDGDG"
}]
```

I was trying to manually map the fields referring the link [Angular 2 observable doesn't 'map' to model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150709/angular-2-observable-doesnt-map-to-model/40947270#40947270) to my model and was able to display those in my HTML by iterating through ngFor.....but I want to also display ncloc and lines value also in the HTML but I am not sure how to map those values to my Model array like mentioned in the above link.
Can you please help me with this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Mode class

```
export class DeiInstance { 
    base_url: string;
    date: string;
    lname : string;
    name : string;
    id : number;
    key:string;

    constructor(obj: DeiInstance) {
        this.sonar_url = obj['base_url'];
        this.lname = obj['lname'];
        this.name = obj['name'];
        this.id = obj['id'];
        this.key = obj['key'];
        this.date = obj['date'];
    } 

    // New static method. 
    static fromJSONArray(array: Array<DeiInstance>): DeiInstance[] {
        return array.map(obj => new DeiInstance(obj));
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Do you have more code of the current mapping and of the current Model?

Comment: Here's my Model :export class DeiInstance 
{
  base_url: string;
  date: string;
  lname : string;
  name : string;
  id : number;
  key:string;

  constructor(obj: DeiInstance) 
  {
    this.sonar_url = obj['base_url'];
    this.lname = obj['lname'];
    this.name = obj['name'];
    this.id = obj['id'];
    this.key = obj['key'];
    this.date = obj['date'];
  }

  // New static method.
  static fromJSONArray(array: Array<DeiInstance>): DeiInstance[] {
    return array.map(obj => new DeiInstance(obj));
  }
}

Comment: @M4R1KU And I am iterating through listProjects defined as DeiInstance[] in my component to display the fields in my HTML

Comment: I assume that you get your data from a backend API so can you add the TypeScript service class and the essential part in your component class.

Comment: sealSearch(term: string) : Observable<DeiInstance[]> 
  {
     return this.http.get(this.sealUrl+term")
               .map(res => DeiInstance.fromJSONArray(res.json()))
               .catch(this.handleError);

  } This is service

Comment: And in component I just subscribe the response to set it to my listProjects array

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can simplify your model and your mapping a lot.
You don't need to map your API response manually. JavaScript/TypeScript can do this for you.

First you need multiple interfaces.

```
export interface DeiInstance { 
    base_url: string;
    date: string;
    lname: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    id: number;
    creationDate: string; //probably date
    version: string
    metrics: Metric[];
    key: string;
 }

 export interface Metric {
      val: decimal;
      frmt_val: decimal;
      key: string;
 }
```

You can then use the `as`-"operator" of **TypeScript** to cast your API response to the DeiInstance Type.

```
 sealSearch(term: string): Observable<DeiInstance[]> {
      return this.http.get(this.sealUrl + term)
           .map(response => response.json() as DeiInstance[])
           .catch(this.handleError);
 }
```

If you use interfaces instead of classes you have also the advantage that you have less production code which will be sended to the client browser.
The interface is only there for pre-compile-time or however you want to call it.

Hope my code works and it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @M4R1KU. It worked for me. If I get any more doubts or I stuck further I would reach out to you. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @RoshDesh nice to hear that. i woul also appreciate it if you would mark my answer as the solution to yozr problem ;D