# Is there a difference between `as` type operator and classical typing in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is there any difference between

```js
const b = 'test' as string;
```

and

```js
const b: string = 'test';
```

Comment: Not in this specific case and in isolation. In short ts recognizes that 'test' is a string and therefore your `b` would be typed as a string anyway. The `as` keyword is typically used for type casting

Comment: Where the correct type can be inferred, as in your example, neither is needed. Where it can't the latter is safer, it lets the compiler verify the assigned value against the type, rather than asserting (albeit with some checking) it is what you say.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple answer `Yes`.

*Explanation*
( replacing `const` with `let` )

`let b: string = 'test'` we are explicitly saying we want `b` to be a string, so assigning anything other than a string to `b` will be a type error.

`let foo = 'hello' as string`
Using `as` is called type assertion, we are telling typescript that , we want `foo` to be this particular type

( for the example you gave, they basically do the same thing ), but the type assertion can also be used in a situation like this

```js
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  occupation: Array<string>
}
// doing this will cause an error because the {} object does not 
// satisfy the contract defined in the User Interface (structurally)
let currentUser: User = {}; 

// in this case what we will do is use type assertion (typescript still does type checking as well
let currentUser: User = {} as User;
```

From your example, the both code do the same thing, but type assertion and explicitly specifying the type of a variable are different

Answer (score 1):

The difference is with normal assignment, the value being assigned must extend the type. But when using the `as` operator, either the value's type can extend the variable's type, or vice versa.  Consider the following code:

```
type Foo = {
    foo: string;
}
let bar = {
    bar: 42
}
type Bar = typeof bar;

let foobar = {
    foo: 'hi',
    bar: 42
}
```

Note that types Foo and Bar are not compatible with each other. However, foobar is both a Foo and a Bar:

```
let foo: Foo;

foo = foobar; // ok, typeof foobar extends Foo
foo = {} as Foo; // ok. Foo extends {}
foo = bar as Foo; // fails, neither Foo nor Bar extends the other

bar = foobar; // ok, foobar extends Bar
foo = foobar; // similarly
foobar = bar; // fails, Bar doesn't extend typeof foobar
```

One of contexts where this makes a difference is the following (which passes type checking):

```
export default {bar: 0, whoops: 'invalid'} as Bar;
```

Although you do get intellisense when creating that object, you can still create properties that shouldn't be there.  So a "workaround" which flags the type error is:

```
const bar: Bar = {bar: 0, whoops: 'invalid'};
export default bar;
```