# TypeScript casting angle brackets vs regular casting

Tags: typescript, casting

In terms of TS type casting using below `Tuple` type as example, is there any significant difference between #1 and #2?

Declaring type `Tuple`:

```
type Tuple = [string, string];
```

#1 Using square brackets before the function argument

```
myFunction(<Tuple>value);
```

#2 Regular type casting

```
myFunction(value as Tuple);
```

Comment: Same thing. `as` was introduced so the former wasn't confused for a JSX tag.

Comment: You probably mean _angle_ brackets (`<>`). Square brackets normally refer to `[]` like for arrays.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any difference between type assertions and the newer \`as\` operator in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503077/any-difference-between-type-assertions-and-the-newer-as-operator-in-typescript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,  It is type assertion not type casting.
The difference is you cannot use `<type>` syntax in `.tsx`  files as the compiler will infer it as an JSX element with no corresponding closing tag.
SO, it is preferred to use `as` way of type assertion as it works everywhere.

```
//if this function is in 'tsx' file, compiler gives errror
myFunction(<Tuple>value); 

//this works everywhere as intended
myFunction(value as Tuple)
```